# Python Pandas DataFrames compare with next rows

Tags: python, dataframe

I have dataframe like this.

```
        col1  
    0     1
    1     3
    2     3
    3     1
    4     2
    5     3
    6     2
    7     2
```

I want to create column out by compare each row. If row 0 less than row 1 then out is 1. If row 1 more than row 2 then out is 0. like this sample.

```
        col1  out  
    0     1   1     # 1<3 = 1
    1     3   0     # 3<3 = 0
    2     3   0     # 3<1 = 0
    3     1   1     # 1<2 = 1
    4     2   1     # 2<3 = 1
    5     3   0     # 3<2 = 0
    6     2   0     # 2<2 = 0
    7     2   -
```

I try with this code.

```
    def comp_out(a):

        return np.concatenate(([1],a[1:] > a[2:]))
    
    df['out'] = comp_out(df.col1.values)
```

It show error like this.

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (11,) (10,)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) instead to "shift" the column up so that rows are aligned with the previous, then use [`lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) to compare less than and [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) convert the booleans to 1/0:

```
df['out'] = df['col1'].lt(df['col1'].shift(-1)).astype(int)
```

```
   col1  out
0     1    1
1     3    0
2     3    0
3     1    1
4     2    1
5     3    0
6     2    0
7     2    0
```

We can strip the last value with [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html) if needed:

```
df['out'] = df['col1'].lt(df['col1'].shift(-1)).iloc[:-1].astype(int)
```

`df`:

```
   col1  out
0     1  1.0
1     3  0.0
2     3  0.0
3     1  1.0
4     2  1.0
5     3  0.0
6     2  0.0
7     2  NaN
```

---

If we want to use the function we should make sure both are the same length, by slicing off the last value:

```
def comp_out(a):
    return np.concatenate([a[0:-1] < a[1:], [np.NAN]])


df['out'] = comp_out(df['col1'].to_numpy())
```

`df`:

```
   col1  out
0     1  1.0
1     3  0.0
2     3  0.0
3     1  1.0
4     2  1.0
5     3  0.0
6     2  0.0
7     2  NaN
```